# IOS: How to connect - disconnect Mobile Data

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I would like to build an Enterprise IOS **(Not published in AppStore)** app that enables the user to:

1. toggle the Airplane mode On/Off

Or if the above is not possible

2. toggle Mobile Data mode On/Off
   I know that in order to do this, I would need to enable entitlements at developers.apple.com for my specific app ID.

What is the library/classes that grant me access to take such actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is possible but Apple has not specific library for it. You can write for it an extension with some effort

---

2. It is possible, Apple has specific library for it as well

   ```
    import Core Telephony // framework

    class CTCellularData : NSObject {  } // class

    enum CTCellularDataRestrictedState : UInt //  the case .restricted that will deny access to cellular data.
   ```

---

**How it works** ?

```
/* create a manager class and make a singleton instance. Check your reachability and handle your state */

class SKManager {

  static let shared = SKManager() 
  private let cellularData = CTCellularData()
  
  private var currentCellularDataState: CTCellularDataRestrictedState = .restrictedStateUnknown

// create this kind of method for checking your state :

func checkReachability(viewController: UIViewController?, completion: (_ restricted: Bool) -> Void) {

let isRestricted = currentCellularDataState == .restricted
    
    guard !isRestricted else {
         // you can trigger a pop up here if you wish
      }
      completion(true)
      return
    }
    completion(false)
  }

}

func handle() {
SKManager.shared.checkApiReachability(viewController: self) { (restricted) in
            if !restricted {
              // you can do not restricted issues here
            } else {
            // your network restricted, so this is your point which you want
         }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I have read the docs for ```class CTCellularData```. My understanding is that this class would enable me as the programmer to restrict the access of my app to Mobile Data. However, I don't see any property where I would be able assign a Boolean value to an object which would enable immediately set Mobile Data to Off state. This is what I need.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/ctcellulardatarestrictedstate
class CTCellularData: An object indicating whether the app can access cellular data.

Plese advise

Comment: to what property should I assign the Bool value or what method should I call to toggle the On/Off state of Mobile Data in the else clause  of ```func handle```?

Comment: yes for on states as you said, for off state in the if clause

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot turn on/off the cellular directly from the application, I've seen apps doing that too many times by just moving the user to settings of that option using an alert.

Comment: I am not going to publish this in  AppStore.  This is why I was thinking it might be possible.

Comment: I don't think so even so i don't think apple provides an API like this to use and then reject if tried to publish, every time I encounter such feature with settings app just directs me to my iOS settings and I can edit them from there, also this will not force the user to turn on/off his cellular this violates privacy Policy

Comment: @MohmmadS: The app isn't going to be released on the app store. In this case code that Apple would reject is just fine.